# How to convert this timestamp string into this format in bash script?

Tags: bash, timestamp

I have a csv file I am reading which contains various time stamps of the format "2016-06-13T18:30:31.868Z". I would like to know how ,using bash script, how to convert the string into "18:30:31" leaving only the time component.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this just with bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
datetime="2016-06-13T18:30:31.868Z"
no_date=${datetime #*T}               # remove "2016-06-13T"
timestamp=${no_date%.*}               # remove ".868Z"
```

or with a regular expression:

```
if [[ $datetime =~ ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]) ]]; then
    timestamp=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to manipulate date-time with a tool that understands it rather than any text-processing tool.

With GNU `date`, you can pass the time format and get the output in desired `HH:MM:SS` format with the `%T` identifier:

```
date -d '2016-06-13T18:30:31.868Z' '+%T'
```

To set a specific timezone, use `TZ` environment variable:

```
TZ=EST date -d '2016-06-13T18:30:31.868Z' '+%T'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash

`VAR="2016-06-13T18:30:31.868Z"`

`FRONT_REMOVED=${VAR%.*}`

`BACK_REMOVED=${FRONT_REMOVED#T*}`

Back Removed should be what you want %.* deletes everything after the period

#T* deletes everything before the T

Answer (score 0):

Use [substring expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion):

```
$ a="2016-06-13T18:30:31.868Z"
$ echo "${a:11:8}"
18:30:31
```